# Show that for $N \ge 2$, $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n= {N \choose 2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

I am not sure where to start with this:

Show that for $N \ge 2$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n= {N \choose 2}$$

It would be appreciated if anyone had hints for how to begin

Comment: prove it by induction on $N$.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} n=\frac{N(N-1)}{2}= {N \choose 2}$ prove the first equality  by induction and the second by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combinatoric argument. Consider a round-robin rock-paper-scissors tournament of $N \geq 2$ people (i.e.: every person plays a game with every other person exactly once). How many games are played in total?

**Method 1:**

- The $1^{\text{st}}$ person plays a game with the other $N - 1$ people once, then sits out.
- The $2^{\text{nd}}$ person plays a game with the other $N - 2$ people once, then sits out.
- The $3^{\text{rd}}$ person plays a game with the other $N - 3$ people once, then sits out.
- ...
- The $(N - 2)^{\text{th}}$ person plays a game with the other $2$ people once, then sits out.
- The $(N - 1)^{\text{th}}$ person plays a game with the last $1$ person once, then sits out.

Adding this up in reverse, the total number of games is:
$$
1 + 2 + \cdots + (N - 1)
$$

**Method 2:**

By definition, there are $\binom{N}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ from $N$ people to play a game together, since order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this is (in my opinion) a combinatorial one. ${N \choose 2}$ counts the number of ways you can choose $2$ 'things' from $N$ distict 'things'. Let these 'things' be the numbers $1$ to $N$. Suppose that $1$ is in the collection of your $2$ chosen numbers. There are $N-1$ different couples you can choose that contain $1$. (i.e the pairs $(1,2),(1,3),...,(1,N)$). Then, how many pairs are there that contain the number $2$ and that you haven't counted already? There are $N-2$. These are $(2,3),(2,4),...,(2,N)$ (note that we've already counted $(1,2)$). Then how many pairs are there that contain $3$ and that we haven't counted yet?.....

This argument can be continued to get your result.

I hope this makes sense. Feel free to ask for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

$n = \binom{n}{1}$, and
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \binom{n}{1} = \binom{N}{2} $$
by the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Answer (score 0):

We count two-element subsets of the set $S = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, N - 1\}$.

Since $S$ has $N$ elements, the number of such subsets is $\binom{N}{2}$.

The left-hand side counts the number of two-element subsets with largest element $n$, where $1 \leq n \leq N - 1$.  To see this, observe that if $n$ is the largest element in a two-element subset, then there are $n$ choices ($0, 1, \ldots, n - 1$) for the smaller element.